# Flutter & Firebase : userCredential.credential.token no longer work after upgrading firebase plugins

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I just upgraded my firebase plugin. And I can no longer get the user token anymore. Is there a new way to get it? Thank you

```
UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

User user = userCredential.user;
final token = await userCredential.credential.token.toString();
```

Comment: "I can no longer get the user token" Why not? If there's an error: what is that error? If there is no error: what is keeping you?

Comment: Can you also please specify the old version that you're used and the new version that you update?